# Editing obviously incorrect code that is not corrected by OP

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

I proposed an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9641261) to an [answer from '12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482171/how-to-get-reference-to-running-service/10482276), which was just rejected. The code, as presented in the answer, is plainly incorrect. The Author has been informed of the fact in the comments 6 months ago, and has not edited out the error (despite still being active on SO, according to his profile). Right now, the code simply does not do what it is supposed to do, and it's a simple case of switching the "true" and "false" return values. It's the first result on Google when you're searching for a not-uncommon problem in Android programming, so it would be useful to have a correct answer.

I have seen that there are a LOT of questions on the topic of edits, and specifically editing code, on meta.SO, and the consensus seems to be "let the OP edit the code him/herself". But since this is obviously not happening here, I am at a loss as to how to proceed now.

Comment: Write your own answer. Credit the existing answer as inspiration.

Comment: @RobertLongson This was my idea as well, but since the (incorrect) answer is already accepted, it will still be shown first. Still, it's better than nothing, so if no better proposal comes up, I'll do that.

Comment: @AndrewT. I am not sure how that code should ever have worked, but nonetheless, I just posted my own answer to the question. Thanks